# Match the column values without seeing the orders

Tags: bash, awk, python

I am trying to compare the value of two columns without seeing the order of it. I tried with summing the values and matching them if matches then putting Match otherwise Nomatch in additional column. But the problem here, sum of two numbers can be the same,
for example:

**dummy thought (which I think can happen as the list is long):**

```
7+5=12;  5+7=12 = Match
6+6=12;  4+8=12 = Nomatch in theory while seeing the numbers but summing them showing the Match.

    locus   truth   predicted
CSF1PO_007-BC03_20171027_2149   11,12   11,12
CSF1PO_007-BC04_20171027_2149   11,12   11,12
CSF1PO_19_20171027_2149 10,12   12,10
CSF1PO_20_20171027_2149 10,0    10,11
CSF1PO_A-10_2018123_1836    12,0    12,13
CSF1PO_A-11_2018123_1836    10,12   12,10
CSF1PO_A-1_20181222_0036    10,11   10,11
CSF1PO_A-12_2018123_1836    11,12   11,12
CSF1PO_A-13_2018123_1836    8,10    10,8
CSF1PO_A-14_2018123_1836    8,11    8,11
```

**Tried so far using summing and match**

```
cat test | sed '1d' | sed 's/,/\t/g' | awk '{print $1"\t"$2+$3"\t"$4+$5}' | awk '{ if ($2 == $3) print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t""Match"; else print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t""NoMatch"}'

Output:
CSF1PO_007-BC03_20171027_2149   23  23  Match
CSF1PO_007-BC04_20171027_2149   23  23  Match
CSF1PO_19_20171027_2149 22  22  Match
CSF1PO_20_20171027_2149 10  21  NoMatch
CSF1PO_A-10_2018123_1836    12  25  NoMatch
CSF1PO_A-11_2018123_1836    22  22  Match
CSF1PO_A-1_20181222_0036    21  21  Match
CSF1PO_A-12_2018123_1836    23  23  Match
CSF1PO_A-13_2018123_1836    18  18  Match
CSF1PO_A-14_2018123_1836    19  19  Match
```

**Note: one more thing has to be in mind that either one number matches with other column's values can be considered as "Matched".**

```
Example:
CSF1PO_20_20171027_2149 10,0    10,11 === Match as one number matches (order does not matter)
CSF1PO_A-10_2018123_1836    12,0    12,13 === Match as one number matches (order does not matter)
```

**One possible solution I tried, which seems working but need clarification or other possible solution.**

```
cat test | sed '1d' | sed 's/,/\t/g' | awk '{ if ($2 == $4 || $2 == $5) print $0 , "=>", "Match"; else if ($3 == $5 || $3 == $4) print $0 , "=>", "Match"; else print $0,"=>","Nomatch"}'

CSF1PO_007-BC03_20171027_2149   11  12  11  12 => Match
CSF1PO_007-BC04_20171027_2149   11  12  11  12 => Match
CSF1PO_19_20171027_2149 10  12  12  10 => Match
CSF1PO_20_20171027_2149 10  0   10  11 => Match
CSF1PO_A-10_2018123_1836    12  0   12  13 => Match
CSF1PO_A-11_2018123_1836    10  12  12  10 => Match
CSF1PO_A-1_20181222_0036    10  11  10  11 => Match
CSF1PO_A-12_2018123_1836    11  12  11  12 => Match
CSF1PO_A-13_2018123_1836    8   10  10  8 => Match
CSF1PO_A-14_2018123_1836    8   11  8   11 => Match
```

Need clarification if I am doing right.
Thanks

Comment: Please give a very simple explanation how one line might look and why it is consiidered a match or no match. This is not so easy to understand from your text. I will try an answer but please try to clarify the exact structure of possible lines (not only by examples but also by a formal description, something like this helps to understand what kind of sed/awk/grep script you need to write)

Comment: CSF1PO_007-BC03_20171027   11,12   11,12    => Match (as both numbers matches from col 3rd to col 4rth).

CSF1PO_19_20171027_2149     10,12   12,10   => Match (as both numbers matches from col 3rd to col 4rth, here order does not matter).

CSF1PO_20_20171027_2149 10,0    10,11 => Match (as atleast one number matches from col 3rd to col 4rth, order does not matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your line structure looks like this:
One line has some random text before the first whitespace. Then there are two whitespace delimited fields. Each of these fields consists of two numbers delimited by a comma.  Additionally it seems that the text before the first whitespace does not have a comma in it.

The first part of your pipeline looks good. So if my assumtion above is correct after executing `cat test | sed '1d' | sed 's/,/\t/g' > test2` we got rid of the title line and now we have just five whitespace delimited fileds. Field 2 and 3 are the first pair of numbers, field 4 and 5 are the second pair.

This is again a bit of guessing on my part because your question was fully clear: in order to match one or both of the fields 2 and 3 must be equal to one or both of the fields 4 and 5.  It does not matter which matches which (they are not considered ordered pairs that need to match).

So you can probably use just one awk snipped instead of two:

```bsh
awk '($2==$4 || $2==$5 || $3==$4 || $3==$5) { print $0 " Match" }' < test2
```

You could also do all this in one awk script because you can tell awk to use whitespace and comma to delimit fields and also to ignore the first line:

```bsh
# -F changes the input field seperator
awk -F '[[:space:],]' '
  # remove the first line
  NR==1 {next}
  # execute block if any of these field combinations match
  ($2==$4 || $2==$5 || $3==$4 || $3==$5) { print $0 " Match" }
  # reverse the condition and print stuff for not matching lines
  ($2!=$4 && $2!=$5 && $3!=$4 && $3!=$5) { print $0 " Nomatch" }
' < test
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but I want "no match" too as I have a long list of the file where some of them are "no match".

```
D18S51_A-13_2018123_1836    14  16  13.2    9 => Nomatch
D18S51_A-16_2018123_1836    13  16  13.2    9 => Nomatch
D18S51_A-9_20181222_0036    13  15  9   13.2  => Nomatch
D18S51_NISTB1_ps109_75ng    13  16  9   13.2  => Nomatch
D18S51_str10or15_BC04       13  14  13.2   18 => Nomatch
D21S11_NISTB1_ps109_75      32  32.2  33   33 => Nomatch
D5S818_str10or15_BC01       11  12  13  10    => Nomatch
FGA_str10or15_BC05          19  22  26  23    => Nomatch
vWA_A-18_2018123_1836       18  0   21  19    => Nomatch
```

Comment: updated my answer